# coq- Prove some expressions do not terminate

Tags: coq

I need to prove this theorem.

```
        Theorem expr_not_terminate:
          ~(forall (e : expr) (s : state),
            exists (v : value),
              evalExpr e s v).
        Proof.
          unfold not.
          intros.
```

As soon as I do 'intros' it brings  'H : forall (e : expr) (s : state), exists v : value, evalExpr e s v' in the hypothesis. and I am not able to do anything on that. How do I break the hypothesis? ANy idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can exhibit a particular expression and a particular state that falsify the claim, and instantiate your hypothesis with those using eg the `specialize` tactic. Then use that hypothesis in the context (probably with induction) to drive a contradiction, allowing you to show false.